# Comment links in /review link to the review page, not the post

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, comment-links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment links on review page lead to nowhere, when they exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132407/comment-links-on-review-page-lead-to-nowhere-when-they-exist)

In the close vote queue (this applies to all queues which display comments)

[image]

Clicking the comment permalink (or right click>copy link location) gives me

```
 http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/7523#comment96568_46824
```

This link is to the review queue, so only >3k users can see it. I feel that it should be:

```
 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46824/a-thought-experiment-with-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle#comment96568_46824
```

i.e, it should link to the comment on the actual post, not in the queue.

Fix please?