# Plot upvotes over time for an answer

Tags: discussion

I searched for this on meta, but couldn't find an answer.

I'm looking for a way to plot question or answer upvotes over time. I'd like to see things like the way an edit affects the number of upvotes or the velocity that a question gains upvotes. You can do this on the site for a user's reputation, but not individual questions or answers.

Like this:

[image]

I'm hoping some smart person has already done this with one of the data tools.

Comment: Nice idea. I don't think we have that yet, but the [timeline view](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4080/timeline) is a start. A UserScript that parses content while on that page and plots a graph sounds plausible.

Comment: other lines such as "Added Bounty" or "Twitted" would be great to have too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *sort of* do this on Data Explorer, although you're restricted by the fact that the `CreationDate` information of votes is limited to the date portion and because you don't have a lot of control over the display of graph.

The `CreationDate` issue won't change as it helps prevent associating votes with users, but if anyone has recommendations on how to improve the graphing functionality, [feedback is welcome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=data-explorer%20feature-request).

As an example, see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/80971?PostId=5436#graph) which produces a graph of votes over time for [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment), using additional plot points to indicate edit dates:

[image: graph of votes over time with markers indicating edits]

Note that at the moment you're also at the mercy of Data Explorer's stale data, but [that should be changing soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732).

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. I tried it on one of my answers (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80971?PostId=1054681#graph) and you can see how an edit caused the graph to get slightly steeper.