# Suggestion: Score timeline graph for individual question

Tags: feature-request, statistics, reputation-graph, vote-count

Just a small suggestion...

I thought it would be interesting to see a graph of how the scoring for a question (and its answers) has changed over time.

I guess for most questions, the bulk of the scoring would be within the first day after it was asked, but many good questions continue getting votes over time.

I guess the real reason for this suggestion is just to feed my appetite for statistics; it's probably not *that* useful most of the time.

That said, I can see how it could show some interesting trends -- for example, a spike in the graph might indicate that an older question suddenly got some fresh attention; maybe because it got linked somewhere, or maybe because it gained a fresh relevance.

Anyway, just a suggestion. I'm sure you've got plenty of other exciting new features to be developing, but it seems to me that this wouldn't be too much of a project.

Thanks for listening.  :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just hit the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)? (Never used it, though it looks like it might fit the bill.)

Comment: well, yes, I'm sure I could (does it do graphs, though?), but I thought it would be nice to have a button on the question page to show a chart on the page for a question.

Comment: If you _really_ love data and statistics, you'll take the raw stuff and make it prettier than anything anyone else could think of. Heck, even a quick graph in Excel looks good these days.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148445/plot-upvotes-over-time-for-an-answer

Comment: @TimStone - yes, that is quite similar to what I was thinking of. I would have multiple lines for the question and for its answers on the same graph, but other than that, yes, the answer on that question is pretty much along the lines of what I had in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, here is a Stack Exchange, *Data Explorer* query for that.  See [**Votes over time for a specific question and its answers**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/83159/).

For example, for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8479058/331508), it outputs [this graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/83159/?PostId=8479058#graph):

[(Click for larger image)
[image: Sample plot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M44nb.gif)

Notes:

1. The question and answer legend is ordered by which got voted on first.  This seems to be a design artifact of the graph engine.
2. SEDE data is currently 4 months stale, but [is promised to go to weekly updates around November-ish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/148310).

Comment: +1 Oh this is nice...

Comment: Oh yes. That is exactly what I was thinking of. Definitely Awesome! Now all we need is a link on the page for each question so I can get to this graph at the push of a button.  ;-)

Comment: You can add that button with a not-too-difficult userscript for your browser (unless it is IE). You could *probably* get this data/plot live (SEDE is a snapshot) using the API, but that's not quite as easy.

Comment: Super fun. [Here's a slight modification](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/675835) that also lets you include anonymous feedback (set IncludeFeedback param to non-zero to include it, you can also set IncludeVotes to 0 if you *only* want to see anonymous feedback).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a graph, but you can see how a question's and its answers' score evolves over time by looking at [the *Timeline*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline?sort=votes&pagesize=50).

For example, see [this timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/934012/timeline):

[(Click for larger view)

[image: Sample timeline]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArHsN.gif)

You can see, that for that question (and its answers), the votes came in steadily, in ones and twos.

Comment: +0.5 for showing an integrated solution and +0.5 for cutting the image in such a nice way :]