# Add the full time to CreationDate column in Votes table in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, data-explorer

I was trying out some queries in Data Explorer and noticed that, column `CreationDate` in table `Votes` doesn't contain the full timestamp. Only the date part is present and time part is set to 00:00:00.

Have a look at [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/140199).

It would be nice to have the full timestamp. Possible uses of this are determining how many votes are cast immediately after posting, how many are cast within an hour, and so on.

I read [the other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/982/152859) where Greg makes the point that:

> up/down voting patterns could strongly correlate with other activity on the site (questions, answers, comments).

But, all these details about posts, comments are available with exact timestamp in User's profile as well as in Data Explorer. The exact voting timestamp can be seen in the Reputation tab. So, if I want to guess who voted me, I can do so by looking at this data. Having exact voting timestamp in Data Explorer won't provide any extra information to aid guessing.

Comment: The exact time is omitted to prevent people from finding out who voted where. Pretty sure it's already explained somewhere... going to search.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148466/161198 @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Voting (up-down) is [anonymous on Data Explorer too](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/140207). So probably the time is not removed for that purpose.

Comment: @Bart found the exact dupe. :)

Comment: Not entirely convinced with the reason. One can check the reputation tab on his profile for the exact time he received the votes.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man OK, I understand - but this requires you to check each user manually. Having the information in the database will make it too easy and harm the privacy of voting.