# Marking comment as favorite?

Tags: feature-request, comments, bookmarks

I found several comments to be more specific to my problem than answer. So, for me comment was an answer and it will be great to mark it as favorite.

Comment: do you mean marking comment accepted - like as [shown and explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165773)?

Comment: No accepted, just favorite like favorites in browser. I want to collect and search my favorite comments like favorite questions. Why? Explained above.

Comment: I see. As of now, one can only bookmark comment URLs in browser using [permalink on their timestamps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/165773 "feature introduced and explained here")

Answer (score 2):

If someone posted a comment that answered a question, then the problem just might be that the comment should have possibly been the beginnings of a fully-fleshed out answer.

Comments are second class citizens. They exist only to serve their masters, the question and the answer. Comments are designed to seek clarification, or help a user improve an answer.

Of course, they're used for a lot more than that, which sometimes leads to information in the comments that might actually belong in an answer. There are a few things you can do in these situations:

- Ask the commenter to write an answer, and hope he/she writes it up.
- Write an answer yourself, using the comment as inspiration. Feel free to mention the user in the answer.
- If an existing answer is related to what's in the comments, consider adding the information to an existing answer.

However, anything that puts more focus on the comments is sort of contrary to the goal of highlighting questions and answers, so a feature allowing users to "favorite" a comment would take away from the content that is most important.

Comment: Sometimes happen that particular comment resolves my problem, not marked answer. Why I can not mark it as my favorite?

Comment: As I mentioned above, dario, comments are second class citizens, so any feature that just serves to make comments feel more important will distract from the more important content. We don't want comments to ever be more important than questions and answers. Q&A is the goal of Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: "We don't want comments to ever be more important than questions and answers." Me either. But as I said there is (in comments) potential. Many informations deserving more attention for personal use -> favorite.

If comments are not so important then why there is possibility to mark them as valuable? Favorite give mi possibility to collect them and search.

Comment: @dario-g, this could make an interesting [StackApp](http://stackapps.com) project. However, I don't see Stack Exchange putting any more development time into drawing more attention to comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it would be great. You can't even favorite answers, only questions.

Think of browser's bookmarks. You can bookmark a website or a web page, you can't bookmark specific content in that page.

Same with posts over the Stack Exchange network: if you find anything useful in some question, favorite the whole question. If you want, create for yourself Excel sheet with "mapping" of what exactly you found useful in each question.

Answer (score 1):

In any case you can only mark posts as favorites.  If the user that made the helpful comment is not interested in converting it into an answer just post the answer yourself and give credit to the original commenter. You can even make your answer a community wiki if you feel uncomfortable gaining reputation from someone elses content...

Comments are not the most important entities on Stack Overflow. Posts should be able to stand on their own without the comments.

Comment: I have a lot of favorites. Many of this favorites have more than 10 answers. Each of them have many comments. Why I must search every time for 'comment that solves **my problem**'?