# Search / filter comments & responses in the Responses profile tab or Star/Favorite for later

Tags: feature-request, search, responses

Would it be possible to add a **Search / Filter** option to the response list in the `Responses` profile tab?  More and more frequently, I find myself wanting to go back to a comment exchange, but if it is more than a couple of days in the past it becomes increasingly difficult to locate. This is especially true if I can't even remember *with whom* I had the comment exchange, and the list just keeps getting longer...

Specifically, my need has been to filter comments rather than revisions or answers; I'm not sure if others would find it broadly applicable over *everything* in the `Responses` tab since the regular search already offers the ability to search answers by user.

I can imagine it being useful to quickly comments by username or text content:

[image: Response/Comment search filter]

#### Or star/favorite them in my list...

Failing this, what about simple functionality to favorite/star a response *in one's own `Responses` list*?  [This question on favoriting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151503/marking-comment-as-favorite) did not find much agreement, but it relates to marking comments as favorites *anywhere* rather than just among one's own responses.

One of my primary reasons for going back in my `Responses` history is for circumstances when I have tried to remind myself to revisit a comment I didn't have time to deal with when I first encountered it.  If I could visit my `Responses` tab to star/favorite it, I would be able, at least, to easily locate it later.

Comment: Yeah, I actually end up using [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) to search for comments if they're sufficiently old. Would be super nice if that was more convenient.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this one soon, it's fairly expensive on the database as-is, would be much more-so filtering on character columns.