# Why are some comment IDs not linked in the API?

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, api

Based on [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&filter=default&site=workplace&run=true), there is inconsistent behavior with the comment ids.

For instance, the first ID is listed as follows:

> "comment_id": 15780,
>
> "post_id": [7622](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7622),

The second is listed as follows:

> "comment_id": [27409](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/my-facebook-wall-is-bothering-some-colleagues-at-work-do-they-have-the-right#comment27409_11660),
>
> "post_id": [11660](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11660),

The third is the same as the first (post link, no comment link), in fact it seems that any comment lower than around number 23,000 doesn't have a link.

Were the way comments are handled changed such that old comments are unable to be rendered as a link? Having a link to the comments would be helpful if it could be added.

Comment: Yes the comment links are available only since [around January 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/152859).

Comment: Thanks @Sha, do you know why previous comments aren't linked?

Comment: Nope, even old comments are now linked, the change was retroactive - so no idea, sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

> …it seems that any comment lower than around number 23,000 doesn't have a link.

Not quite. The console makes a separate request to get the link for each comment (although this is technically unnecessary as it could just linked to the `/posts/comments/{id}` route), grouping the returned comment IDs from your API call into a single request.

Unfortunately, while it *requests* 100 separate comments, it fails to set the page size for the response to be 100, so you end up with just the 30 most recent comments in the returned results, and those are the comments that are linked.

While the fix would be to include the `pagesize` parameter, using the aforementioned route might be just as easy and a little more efficient when rendering the results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm not a developer, so while I understand what you're saying in theory, [I am stuck at a much more basic level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202641). Is there any plan to make the API more accessible for computer-illiterati like me who believe that Excel is the pinnacle of human computing?

Comment: Well, hopefully it'll prompt a Stack Exchange developer into fixing the problem, since it's fairly trivial. To your other question though, I'm not sure that I have a good answer beyond that perhaps I could put some samples on Stack Apps somewhere.

Comment: if you could, that would be a huge help. Just something simple like *"This is how you run a API call to get all the pages of results and stick them in a javascript/JSON/something usable object"*. That should be basic (I would think), but I can't find that very simple info anywhere, and despite my fiddling just couldn't get it to work.